# How to define a function which cannot return anything in TypeScript

Tags: function, typescript, return-type

I am writing an API which has 2, very similar, functions:

```
function update(f: () => string) {...}
function updateDeep(f: () => void) {...}
```

As you can see, I am trying to make sure that the client of my API passes the correct function type depending on which function they call.

The first function, `update`, works as predicted. This will rightly throw a compilation error:

```
update(() => console.log('hey'));
```

The second function, `updateDeep`, does not throw a compilation error event though it should:

```
updateDeep(() => 'hey');
```

**How to I declare a function type which does not return anything?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible to make this happen. As the recipient of a function, your only ability is to set a *lower* bound on what kind function is provided.

See also the TypeScript FAQ entry: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void

Comment: Thanks. I suppose I'll use a runtime check instead.