# Why can I override void return type with non-void in implementation of abstract method (and not vice versa)?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering why the following TypeScript code compiles without error or warning (using tsc).

```
abstract class A {
  abstract foo(): void;
}

class B extends A {
  foo(): number { // this is fine?
    return 1;
  }
}
```

I am seemingly able to create an abstract class with an abstract method that has a void return type, but the implementing class can use a non-void return type and still count as implementing said abstract method.

On the other hand, I am (correctly in my mind) *not* allowed to declare the abstract method with a non-void return type and use a void return type in the implementation (or any type that is different from the declaration).

```
abstract class A {
  abstract foo(): string;
}

class B extends A {
  foo(): void {
    console.log('does not compile');
  }
}
```

Why is it okay to override a void return type? Should it be? Is this a bug in the compiler or intended behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: There's an old proposal related to this, still open: [add a flag to disable () => void being subtype of () => a](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8584)

Comment: @artem interesting discussion!

Comment: There's a [FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void) for that.  Notice that overriding a function follows the same assignability rules as assigning a value to a variable.

Comment: If you really care, you can use the return type `undefined` instead of `void`.  They are similar (the caller will get an `undefined` value at runtime in either case) but possibly closer to your intent.  Of course an implementation of an `undefined`-returning function needs to explicitly `return undefined` instead of implicitly (with just `return` or leaving off `return`), so it's up to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a function which cannot return anything in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019100/how-to-define-a-function-which-cannot-return-anything-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the typescript spec:

> The Void type is a subtype of the Any type

So we can infer that `void` behaves much like `any`, since it is its subtype, i.e. you can redefine (narrow-down) `void` type to something more specific like `string`, just like `any`.

P.S. There isn't much information on `void` in TS docs or spec.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#325-the-void-type

Comment: Oh I see. So do I understand it correctly that it isn't possible to restrict/detect implementing methods to not return a value because of this?

Comment: I guess, yes (not possible), just like if you'd use `any`.